# Transferring data from old macbook to new macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, data-transfer

Is there an easy way to transfer my applications and data from my old macbook pro to my new macbook pro?  I vaguely recall a service or utility that transferred "everything" from an old macbook to a new macbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean the [*Migration Assistant*](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4413).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Firewire 800 cable.  Start the old one up in target disk mode (hold T while it boots,) and it mounts as an external drive on the new one.  Drag over stuff that's in your /Applications, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Time Machine**. Although I prefer having a fresh install. One thing I've found great is [**Dropbox**](http://www.dropbox.com). If all your files are also stored here, you can automatically download them once your OS is ready by installing it (Dropbox).